# Grep two parts from a column name in dataset

Tags: r, regex, shiny, subset

I have a dataset with column names in the format : *textyear* like :**John2011**, **Jack2012**.

Is it possible to subset a specific column from the dataset using:

```
selectInput("name",...
sliderInput("year",...
```

if in selectInput **name** user enters name like: **John** etc and in selectInput **year** user enters year like: **2011**

Comment: What's keeping you from it?`paste0(input$name, input$year)` will generate the column name in the server function.

Comment: AlexR thank you. Is it possible to use this strategy to get something like: new_df <- old_df %>% select(col1, grep(paste0(input$name, input$year)))??

Comment: `select_(.dots = c("col1", paste0(input$name, input$year)))`. Why even bother using `grep`?

Comment: This seems excellent. What if I want to merge some static text **Mr** between two inputs like JohnMr2011, JackMr2012. This text is not an input from user, just a part in every column name? I tried select_(.dots = c("col1", paste0(input$name, ""Mr", input$year))) without success

Comment: I think if you look at the docs, you'll figure that out on your own.

Comment: Thank you Alex you are right. Can you post your answer so I check it as correct? You helped me very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the column name by using `paste0`:

```
colName <- paste0(input$name, input$year)
```

Then you can select the column with `dplyr` using the SE-variant of `select`:

```
select_(dataframe, .dots = colName)
```

Additonal columns can be selected by giving `select_` a character vector:

```
select_(dataframe, .dots = c("StaticColumn", colName))
```